# Set cookie with SuperWebSocket

Tags: c#, cookies, websocket

Using [SuperWebSocket](https://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) in a C# project, is it possible to set a custom cookie header in the response, like a session cookie?

Comment: Just in case you do not find the way to do this in SuperWebSocket, take a look at this: https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Hooking-into-the-HTTP-negotiation

Comment: @vtortola Thanks for the suggestion! It seems SuperWebSocket doesn't allow hooking into the HTTP negotiation. I will evaluate WebSocketListener as an alternative to switch to.

Comment: No problem. If you feel anything missing let me know through GitHub. I am always interested in real case scenarios :)